# How can I enable CORS for a quorum node from the geth console?

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum

I have a remote quorum node that I am trying to connect my metamask wallet to but it needs to have CORS enabled but I created my network with quorum-wizard and I can only connect to a node using attach.sh that was generated when I created it. When I run ./attach.sh 1 to connect to node 1 it connects but when I run

```
 --rpccorsdomain "*"
```

from the geth console I get

```
(anonymous): Line 1:17 Unexpected string
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a localhost address:

```
--rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:8080"
```

Or without the backticks:

```
--rpccorsdomain=*
```